# PhpSpreadsheet official recipe "Write a date or time into a cell" not working as excpected

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am following the recipe [Write a date or time into a cell](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#write-a-date-or-time-into-a-cell) from official PHPSpreadsheet doc.

The only difference is that the 3 writes are on 3 different cells.

```php
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell::setValueBinder( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\AdvancedValueBinder() );

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('D1', '2008-12-31');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);

// PHP-time (Unix time)
$time = gmmktime(0,0,0,12,31,2008); // int(1230681600)
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('D2', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExcel($time));
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D2')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);

// Excel-date/time
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3', 39813);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D3')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Ods($spreadsheet);
$writer->save("/var/www/html/var/test.ods");
```

Opening the ods file with LibreOffice Calc, I have the 3 cells setted with content `39813` and no date formatting is applied.
[image]

Is the doc wrong or am I missing something?